# Accessing ENV files in Vite Version 4

Tags: javascript, vite, project-structure

I am working on a web application built using HTML/CSS/JS + Vite.js.  We were running on Vite v2.8.3 and wanted to upgrade to the latest v4.3.3. I was able to successfully complete the update and run the server, but then found that I was no longer able to access the variables in my DOTENV file. Nothing about the files or the file structure changed - all I did was update to the latest Node.js and Vite.js.  The ENV files only stopped working after I updated Vite.

I was able to solve the problem by moving the ENV file one level down in my file structure -- but this concerns me since I don't understand why that change was necessary.

Here's my file structure:

```
web-app/
  |-- www-vite
      |-- pages
      |-- index.html
      |-- main.js
      |-- style.css
      |-- vite.config.js
      |-- package.json
      |-- package-lock.json
      |-- node_modules
      |-- .gitignore
  |-- .env.development // Only works when I move it one level down into www-vite directory 
  |-- .env.production // Only works when I move it one level down
```

Here is what the Vite docs have to say about [ENV variables and modes](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html). Here's the migration [guide from v2](https://v3.vitejs.dev/guide/migration.html), as well as the migration [guide from v3](https://vitejs.dev/guide/migration.html). I found that updating Vite at all, even just from 2.8.3 to 2.9.5, broke the ENV variables.

My DOTENV file looks like this:

```
VITE_ENDPOINT_BASE_URL = (private URL goes here)
```

Then I grab the ENV variable in the main.js file like so:

```
export const endpoint_base_url = import.meta.env.VITE_ENDPOINT_BASE_URL; 
// Returns undefined after updating Vite, only works after I move it into www-vite directory
```

Here's what my config file looks like. I tried adding "envDir" and pointing to the correct file per the [docs](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#envdir), but that didn't work. I see there's an option to use a [loadENV helper](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html), but i'm not sure how to integrate that with what I already have in my config file. I'm also wondering if I need to do this at all, or if it's fine to just move the .env files into the `www-vite` directory.

vite.config.js

```
const { resolve } = require("path");
const { defineConfig} = require("vite");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: {
        envDir: "../.env.production", // Does not work
        main: resolve(__dirname, "index.html"),
        login: resolve(__dirname, "./pages/login/login.html"),
        home: resolve(__dirname, "./pages/home/home.html"),
        recap: resolve(__dirname, "./pages/recap/recap.html"),
        leaderboards: resolve(
          __dirname,
          "./pages/leaderboards/leaderboards.html"
        ),
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: So you want to put the file in the parent dir?

Comment: Yes, or rather, I don't want to move it out of the parent dir, where it was previously working before I updated vite.

Answer (score 2):

To change the default env path you can set it in your vite config

[Vite Docs](https://vitejs.dev/config/shared-options.html#envdir)

```js
export default defineConfig({
  envDir: '../'
})
```

Comment: thanks so much, I didn't find this in the docs. I tried adding it to my config file, but still got the same error. Wondering if you could take another look at my post? I updated it with my config file code at the bottom.

Comment: Also wondering if there's any reason not to just move the files down one level into the `www-vite` directory? I don't want to break the production pipeline.

Comment: It depends on your project. Maybe you have to share same env in multiple project.